# Eclipse IType class ignoring compile errors

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I've been trying to produce a compile error by defining wrong typed field in an IType, however, when searching for problems within the project containing the Class File that the IType stands for, there is no error.

I have no idea how to understand such result, is that supposed to happen? Is it acceptable for a IType to contain methods or fields that works with undefined classes?

My goal is to detect if such errors are simply ignored or they do not happen at all.

As asked below, this is the code i hope to produce the error:

```
String source = "private Asdf a;";
itype.createField(source, null, true, null);        
String jmethod = "\tpublic void foo() {\n\t\tint b = a.getB();\n\t}\n";
itype.createMethod(jmethod, null, true, null);
```

Where Asdf is never defined.

Comment: Please include a code snippet.  How are you adding the field?  Is this on a binary or source type?

Comment: I'm creating field and methods using the IType API:
createField();
createMethod();

Comment: And how do you check to see if there is an error?

Comment: i call on the findMarkers function of the class IProject, on the IProject that contains such class file

`project.findMarkers(IJavaModelMarker.JAVA_MODEL_PROBLEM_MARKER, true, IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is either that your call to `findMarkers` isn't waiting long enough and the build isn't completed yet, or that the call to `createField` isn't triggering a build at all.

Problems are only discovered after a compile or a reconcile. There are lots of internal ways to get access to problems after a compile, but if you want to stay API-compliant, then your best bet is to create a compilationParticipant.  See the class `org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.CompilationParticipant` and the associated extension point called `org.eclipse.jdt.core.compilationParticipant`.  Implementing one of these will ensure that your code is triggered whenever an operation occurs that forces the computing of problems.

Comment: Thanks Andrew,
It seems that the CompilationParticipant extension needs of a ReconcileContext that i cannot find  how to obtain. Do you know how do i get it?

Comment: This class is part of the jdt.core project.  It is `org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.ReconcileContext`.

Comment: I'm still stuck trying to find an instance of ReconcileContext. It doesn't seems to be any information about it. 
I suppose that i am missing something about what to do with the CompilationParticipant.

Comment: The framework instantiates the instance of `ReconcileContext`.  You must implement the `compilationParticipant` extension point and provide it with your own implementation of `CompilationParticipant`. Your implementation will be called whenever there is a reconcile or a compile event. The only way that you can "get" an instance of this is to force a build.